# Why wrap a function definition in an immediate function?

Tags: javascript, closures

Is there any advantage of wrapping a function definition in an immediate anonymous function?

Here is an example from the [jsfeat](http://inspirit.github.io/jsfeat/) library:

```
var get_channel = (function () {
    return function(type) {
        return (type & 0xFF);
    }
})();
```

Or is it better to just do the following?

```
var get_channel = function(type) {
    return (type & 0xFF);
};
```

It seems that in this case there are no advantages in favour of the first version:

1. It's longer and harder to read,
2. It takes up more memory, because the closure keeps a reference to the
   outer activation object, but there is no useful data in it,
3. Sometimes it would be slower (at least in theory), because it takes longer to access global variables if the engine has to go through a longer scope chain.

Comment: Your particular example seems pointless. An outer function that actually retains some data via an argument or local variable(s) is not pointless.

Answer (score 2):

There are some advantages, but they aren't visible in the example you've provided. The advantages are that you can

1. Create a cleaner *function* by having data captured in scope, making function logic not obstructed or obfuscated by the data. This is especially helpful if the data needs to be constructed but is expected to be the same every time thereafter, or if you want to have data shared across multiple invocations which does not cause conflicts in the global namespace.
2. Choose what *function* to return depending on the environment or some calculation. This saves you have to run the same calculations over and over again.

For example, you could make a cross-browser *XHR function* like this

```
var XHR = (function () {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
            return function () {
                return new XMLHttpRequest();
            };
        else
            return function () {
                return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            };
    }());
```

Now future calls of `XHR` don't need to work out the `if` logic, which would always be the same anyway.